# primefaces textEditor fonts

Tags: primefaces, quill

Does anybody know how to add more font styles to the Primefaces textEditor component.  The showcase only shows three fonts available, whereas the deprecated editor component had multiple font styles to choose from.

Comment: See the documentation (PDF). It refers to https://quilljs.com/guides/how-to-customize-quill/

Comment: I've tried looking there, but it points to styling the component.  I'm guessing it can't be done.